# Replace array values from the reference list

Tags: python, numpy

I want to replace the values of 'data' array using 'ref' list:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 9 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 15 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 12 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0]])

ref = [9,12]
```

I tried as:

```
data[data==ref] = 0

print data
```

But No change.

The expected array should have the 9 and 12 values in it replaced by 0.
How's the fastest way of doing it?

Comment: I am looking for NumPy way of doing it.

Comment: I think you mean `ref = [12,9]`? ... the first number is the row number ... or what do you mean with "9 and 12 values in it"

Comment: @plonser No, its separate list of numbers

Comment: One method would be to compare each element in the list like so `data[np.where(data == ref[0])] = 0` and then again for `ref[1]`

Comment: There is a NumPy way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over the values and use `np.where` to mask your array to set the values:

```
In [67]:

ref = [9,12]
for e in ref:
    data[data == e] = 0
data
Out[67]:
array([[ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  1, 15,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

The reason this fails:

```
data[data==ref] = 0
```

is you are comparing an array with a list which will result in a scalar boolean value of `False` this is why it does nothing.

Just to show that @haave's answer works and in my opionion is better:

```
In [73]:

data[np.in1d(data, ref).reshape(data.shape)] = 0
data
Out[73]:
array([[ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  1, 15,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Comment: Any problem on using it?

Comment: Sorry problem with what?

Comment: `where` is not necessary, `data[data == e] = 0` is actually enough

Comment: No not really, for loop is fine,

Comment: @Vincent thanks for pointing that out, I get so used to using `where` so often

Answer (score 5):

Iterating through a numpy array is very slow, order of magnitude slower than iterating through a Python list.

With the following construct you keep it all within numpy, using the `numpy.in1d()` method (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html)

The following sets all elements that are in `ref` to -1 and is trivially changed to setting them to 0

```
data[np.in1d(data, ref).reshape(data.shape)] = -1
```

Comment: As it's trivial to set to `0` why not just do this in your answer as the OP has asked? +1 by the way

Comment: I liked `-1` better to check if it indeed worked - there were no `-1`s in the original data array and a lot of zeroes :-)

Comment: Yes I guess the OP's sample dataset would make it hard to see exactly where the difference is

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
data[np.logical_or(*(data == e for e in ref))] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to achieve the desired output -

```
data[np.any(data == np.asarray(ref)[:,None][:,None],0)] = 0
```

Basically, we convert `ref` to a `numpy array` with `np.asarray` giving us a vector. Then, *send* all its elements to the third dimension and perform `equality-check` against the 2D array `data`, giving as  a boolean array of matches between `data` and `ref` in a 3D array. Finally, we perform `np.any` to look for any matches across the third dimension, giving us a 2D mask, which we can use to index into `data` and set the matching ones to `0`.